# How to read the specified partition of a COMPO partition table?

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb

I create a partitioned database with COMPO domain, which schema is shown as follows:

```py
partitionSchema->([2021.01.31,2021.01.30,2021.01.29,2021.01.28,2021.01.27,2021.01.26,2021.01.25,2021.01.24,2021.01.23,2021.01.22,...],10)
databaseDir->dfs://StockTick
engineType->OLAP
partitionSites->
partitionTypeName->[VALUE,HASH]
partitionType->[1,5]
```

The first level of partitions is VALUE domain, and the second level of partitions is HASH domain.

How to read the data in each partition?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to read the data of partition /level2/20210813/Key0. You may use this piece of script:

```
select  * from loadTable("dfs://StockTick","bond_tick") where trade_date=2021.08.13,partition(secu_code, 0)
```